# Getting a record with a MAX value across several join tables

Tags: mysql, sql, schema

Schema:
[image: The schema for the question.]

[image]

**Goal (assuming this schema must remain the same):**

> What is the most recent outreach for the first salesperson created per company?

1. For each record in the company table, get the corresponding record in the company_salesperson table using a matching company_salesperson.customer_id value and the MAX(company_salesperson.created_at) value.

- {For the company record w/ id == 1: this should return company_salesperson record w/ id == 2}

2. For each returned company_salesperson record, get all company_salesperson_company_outreach records with a matching company_salesperson_company_outreach.company_salesperson_id value

- For the company_salesperson record w/ id == 2, this should return two company_salesperson_company_outreach records w/ id's 2 and 3

3. For each set of returned company_salesperson_company_outreach records, get the corresponding company_outreach record withe the MAX(company_outreach.outreach_id)

- For the company_salesperson_company_outreach records w/ id's 2 and 3, we should get corresponding company_outreach records w/ id's 2 and 3. Based on their company_outreach.outreach_id values, this should see that company_outreach record w/ id == 3 has a greater company_outreach.outreach_id value. Therefore this should return company_salesperson_company_outreach record w/ id == 3.

Desired Output:

```
SELECT company.id, company_salesperson.id, company_salesperson_company_outreach.id, company_outreach.id
FROM ...???
```

| company.id | company_salesperson.id | company_salesperson_company_outreach.id | company_outreach.id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 3 |

I feel that there is a very elegant solution to this, but after three days of my brain melting out of my ears, I was advised to reach out here! Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to get this result by using nested subqueries, e.g.:

```sql
SELECT c.company_id,
  csco.company_salesperson_id,
  csco.id,
  c.outreach_id
FROM company_outreach c
  INNER JOIN company_salesperson_company_outreach csco
    on c.id = csco.company_outreach_id
WHERE c.Id = (
  SELECT MAX(company_outreach_id)
  FROM company_salesperson_company_outreach
  WHERE company_salesperson_id = (
    SELECT MIN(id)
    FROM company_salesperson
    WHERE company_id = c.company_id
    AND created_at = (
      SELECT MIN(created_at)
      FROM company_salesperson
      WHERE company_id = c.company_id
    ) 
  )
)
```

Doesn't feel to be "very elegant" as you requested, but it's the best I was able to come up with.

Comment: You freaking rock Umberto! Thank you so much for this reply, it is FAR more elegant than what I had been working on. I'll give it a try now!

Comment: I just tried this and it essentially wont run. I think the logic is solid and I understand your method, but the data set might be too large for this query to run. The first test took about 8 minutes before I stopped the query.